# iOS Ad Hoc Distribution - starting 12 months testing period halfway through Apple Developer Program

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

Morning all,

We would like to release our app via Apples Ad Hoc distribution. We "can register up to 100 devices per product family per year that your team uses for development and testing." Our developer account is up for renewal on 20th January, but we want to release on 1st September. Does this mean that the app will stop working for testers on 20th January or will it run for 12 months from 1st September? We need it to run for 12 months from the initial release date, is there anything we need to be aware of to ensure this happens?

Huge thanks in anticipation of your help!

Answer (score 0):

IOS certificate is only one year validity, after the need to re-apply for iOS authentication package IPA use